# distance in kms from lat long for all locations in the dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
lat <- c(28.7041,19.0760,12.9716)
long <- c(77.1025,72.8777,77.5946)
place <- c('A','B','C')
input_df <- data.frame(place,lat,long)
```

I want the distance b/w each place in kms in the following format

```
df <- data.frame(Location1 = c("A","B",'C'),
                 Location2 = c("A","B",'C'),
                 Dist_in_KMS = c())
```

Comment: What have you tried? What packages do you want to use? It's helpful to see some code in order to know how you're approaching the question. It's unclear because your example just has the distances between point A & A, which is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not say anything about the projection. So, I assume that `crs = 4326`.

```
packs <- list("tidyverse", "magrittr", "sf")
lapply(packs, require, character.only = T)

lat <- c(28.7041,19.0760,12.9716)
long <- c(77.1025,72.8777,77.5946)
place <- c('A','B','C')
input_df <- data.frame(place,lat,long)

df <- st_as_sf(input_df, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  st_distance() %>% 
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
  set_colnames(c("A", "B", "C")) %>% 
  mutate(Location1 = c("A", "B", "C")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(!Location1, names_to = "Location2", values_to = "Dist_in_KMS") %>% 
  mutate(Dist_in_KMS = as.numeric(Dist_in_KMS) / 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
library(geosphere)
with(
    df,
    `dimnames<-`(
        distm(cbind(long, lat)) / 1e3,
        rep(list(place), 2)
    )
)
```

which gives

```
         A         B         C
A    0.000 1149.6084 1742.6509
B 1149.608    0.0000  843.1129
C 1742.651  843.1129    0.0000
```